# LXD 2.0 - lxd.migration to snap hang waiting for lxd process to start - /var/lib/lxd directory gone

Tags: snap, lxc, lxd

As the title said migration to snap went wrong and I lost all the /var/lib/lxd directory except for the storage_pool and images which were symbolic links.

Obviously I lost all configurations but I noticed that each container has the metadata and backup metadata intact. I can probably reconstruct some of the bridged macvlan profile but not necessarily all the containers.

Q1. Is there a way to import existing containers or reconstruct the lxd.db?
Q2. Is there a specific forum for LXD/LXC where I can ask? Or just file a bug report on github?

Answer (score 0):

The discussion forum for LXD (and LXC 1.0) is
https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/